# Codingbat how to count if there are three 3 in an array

Tags: java

Java newbie here, I'm doing some practice about array on [Codingbat haveThree](http://codingbat.com/prob/p109783). This is the question :"Given an array of ints, return true if the value 3 appears in the array exactly 3 times, and no 3's are next to each other." My code works on most situation but not all.

My code:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums){
    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length-2;i++){
      if(nums[i]==3){
        counter++;
      }
      if(counter==3){
        return true;
      }
   }
      return false;
}
```

[image: The tester]

Can anyone help me and tell me where I was wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: @KenWhite Sorry about that, But I was trying to post the test, but when I submit it always shown to me there is a error I can not post.

Comment: @KenWhite I added a pic of the situation it works on, hope you can check the pic

Comment: What I don't get: the assignment clearly describes TWO situations where this test should return true. But your code only checks one of the two possibilities. And then you are surprised that you fail a lot of tests?

Comment: @GhostCat Sorry I don't get what do you mean, first of all I did not surprised, and then I came to here looking for help and improve my code so that I can learn how to fix that and I will be careful next time, but from your comment I feel like you think this is a stupid question I asked, you are probably a master of java but I said I'm the newbie of java. If I can understand all of staffs about java without learning I won't come here and ask people for help!

Comment: The point is: such challenges are meant to be solved by sitting down... until they are solved. Asking other people for help should be your last resort. And it looks like you took up the challenge and stopped halfway. Your code implies that only focused on the easy part of that assignment. You didn't even mention which part of the second test makes your head spin. Thing is: one learns programming by trying trying trying. In other words: you describe two problems. But the first one is solved, and you are not showing a single line that implies you even tried to solve problem 2 on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Given an array of ints, return true if the value 3 appears in the
>   array exactly 3 times, and no 3's are next to each other."

you're almost there, however, there are a few mistakes and incomplete implementations:

1. you didn't check if the value `3` is next to another value `3` (in which case we return `false`)
2. you return as soon as `count == 3` even though you didn't search the entire array to conclude that there is no more `3s`.
3. as it stands your loop condition `i < nums.length-2` doesn't include the last two elements of the array within the search.

---

solution:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums){
       int counter = 0;
       for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
           if(nums[i] == 3){
              counter++;
           }

           if(i + 1 < nums.length) {
              if (nums[i] == 3 && nums[i + 1] == 3) return false;
           }
       }

       if(counter == 3) return true;
       return false;
}
```

Comment: I understand it but there is a part confuse me, `if(i+1<nums.length)` can I change to `if(i<nums.length-1)`?

Comment: @ZhuangzhuangLi sure you can it's the same thing.

Comment: I see so my problem was when I run the loop if the loop find `nums[i]=3` so it will exit the loop and return something but I dont go through every elements in this array right? @Ousmane Mahy Diaw

Comment: @ZhuangzhuangLi read my post from the top you'll see your mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for this, Have a look :)

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
  boolean check=true;
  int count = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){

    if( nums[i]==3 && count++>0 && ( (i>0 && nums[i-1] == 3) || (i<nums.length-1 && nums[i+1] == 3) ) )
    {//just checking if there are any consecutive 3's next to each other and counting them 
      check = false;
    }
  }


  return (check && count==3);//count should be 3 and no 3's should be next to each other

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, which passed all the tests on CodingBat:

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
  int counter3 = 0;
  
  if (nums.length >= 5) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] == 3) {
        counter3++;
      }
    }
  }
    
  if (counter3 == 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length - 4; i++) {
      if ( (nums[i] == 3) && 
           (nums[i+1] != 3) && 
           (nums[i+2] == 3) && 
           (nums[i+3] != 3) && 
           (nums[i+4] == 3)
         ) { return true; }
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your loop does not lookup for each element you are missing the last 2 ones. Should be `i < nums.length` or use simply enhanced for so you don't have to save the current num on a value.
2. Check if no 3's are next to each other, because now you aren't checking that. I think the best salution to secure that no 3's are next to each other is to save the last number and compare it to the current one.
3. You can only be sure that the value 3 appears exactly 3 times in the array if you had seen the whole array so check that at the end and not in the loop.

   ```
   public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
    int lastNum = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (int currNum : nums) {
        if (currNum == 3) {
            counter++;
            if (lastNum == currNum) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        lastNum = currNum;
    }
    return counter == 3;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**A very Simple solution for this problem:**

```
public boolean haveThree(int[] nums) {
  int count = 0;
  int preNum = 0;
  for(int i =0; i<nums.length;i++){
    if(nums[i]==3){
      count++;
      if(preNum ==3){
        return false;
      }
    }
    preNum = nums[i];
  }
  return count == 3;
}
```